# How to load binary properties with Microsoft.OData.Client?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata

I am using `Microsoft.OData.Client (7.18.0)` and have the following code in a Blazor component that is pulling data from an OData WebAPI:

```
var reportData = await Odata.ReportData.ByKey(ReportData.Id).GetValueAsync();
```

The metadata looks like this:

```
<EntityType Name="ReportData">
    <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="Id"/>
    </Key>
    <Property Name="ReportFiles" Type="Edm.Binary" MaxLength="-1"/>
    <Property Name="ReportInformation" Type="Edm.Binary" MaxLength="-1"/>
</EntityType>
```

The json repsonse in the browser debugging is as it should be:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "redacted",
    "@odata.type": "#Models.ReportEngine.ReportData",
    "@odata.id": "redacted",
    "@odata.editLink": "ReportData(redacted)",
    "ReportFiles@odata.type": "#Binary",
    "ReportFiles": "eyJlNjJlMjA0Zi00OWM5LTRiY2ItOTI5OS0G.....==",
    "ReportInformation@odata.type": "#Binary",
    "ReportInformation": "eyJlNjJlMjA0Zi00OWM5LTRiY2ItOTI5OS0G.....=="
}
```

Unfortunately, when analyzing the result from `GetValueAsync()` all binary properties are `null`.

It does not help to add a delay or wait some seconds before processing the data. Is there an issue with `GetValueAsync()` or am I doing something wrong?